# How to make a copy of an object and compare with the original

Tags: java

I need to make a copy of the following object and compare it to the original but I have no idea where to begin.

```
Administrator admin = new Administrator(first, last, 
     new Date(month,day,year), salary, title, department, supervisor);
```

I have tried researching `copy` and `clone` methods but I can not seem to grasp it.

Comment: write it yourself?

Comment: I need to use those methods

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Comment: Grasp which parts? You just call those methods as-is

Comment: What is the `copy` method? And who upvoted this??

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the clone method, your classes must implement the Cloneable interface.

Check the sample code below.

```
public class MyClass implements Cloneable {
   private String text;
   private int size;

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }
   public void setText(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }
   public int getSize() {
      return size;
   }
   public void setSize(int size) {
      this.size = size;
   }

   public MyClass clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
      return (MyClass)super.clone();
   }
}
```

Cloning...

```
try{
   MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
   myClass.setSize(6);
   myClass.setText("sample");

   MyClass myClass2 = myClass.clone();
} catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Make sure that you override the equals method properly for object comparison.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions. Fix the warnings in your code. What if the object contains other mutable objects; do you need a shallow or a deep clone?

Comment: It is just a sample. It is true that exception may occur especially when there are objects that are not cloneable.